# Is there a way to allow-list rspec tests that reach out to external domains?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

We have several React apps that are embedded in our platform's controllers, served from S3 AWS domains. By default, rspec seems to disallow having `<script src="https://some-external-dns.com/scripts.js"></script>` in your code being tested, and instead asks that you "stub" your script request and response using something like this:

```rb
stub_request(:get, "https://foo-box.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/login-hero-manifest.json").with(
  headers: {
    'Accept' => '*/*',
     'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3',
     'Host' => 'foo-box.s3.amazonaws.com',
    'User-Agent' => 'Ruby'
   }
).to_return(
  status: 200,
     body: {
    environment: "prod",
       name: "feature-administration",
      url: "https://foo-box.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/login-hero.js"
       }.to_json
)
```

I get this in theory, but if we know this is a trusted domain, I would prefer us just resolve the response so we can test against it (also stubbing out hundreds of requests/responses across hundreds of tests feels completely unintuitive and unsustainable.

I am not super well-versed in Ruby/rspec, but I was hoping there was some way to allow-list code that comes back from `foo-box.s3.amazonaws.com`.

Answer (score 0):

`stub_request` is actually a feature of a tool called WebMock, not RSpec.

WebMock is used to prevent your test suite from making slow, flaky external web requests while the test suite is running. If you were to actually make these requests to S3, your tests would fail any time S3 is down, or any network link between you and S3 goes down or slows down. (Unusual, for sure. But, it has happened.)

So, the code in your question is actually preventing you from making the HTTPS call to `foo-box.s3.amazonaws.com` and instead responding with the status code and body that you specify. This is a good thing. It will make your tests more reliable and performant.

As for whether or not this is sustainable, it depends on what you're testing. In the example above, the test seems to be validating the contents of a JSON file on S3. Which part of that test is important to you? Ensuring that the JSON in the file is correct? Or, ensuring that S3 returns the file you expect when you request it.

Since there's really no point testing that S3 returns the correct file when you request it -- Amazon's engineers have presumably done this for you -- you can safely ignore S3 here and focus on the content of the file. That means you can remove WebMock from the test and stick with plain old RSpec.

Assuming the file was generated dynamically and placed on S3 by your code (or maybe your build/deploy process), you should be able to test the portion of the code that generated the contents without testing the portion of the code that uploaded it to / downloaded it from S3.